# Why do my DOM elements lose their location attributes when I size my SVG based on container size?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In order to make a joint [map/scatterplot chart of mine](https://s3.amazonaws.com/blinderman-lede/missed_connections/map_and_scatter_v2.html) responsive, I've adjusted the SVG dimensions based on the container size (as Chris Amico suggests doing [here](http://eyeseast.github.io/visible-data/2013/08/26/responsive-d3/)). My original map works well enough — when you click the "posts/population" button, there's a simple fade out of the map, and the circles line up in a logical way.

Here's what the code looks like for my SVG setup (nothing fancy, just giving this as background to show the changes I made). In the body, I had:

```
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
  </svg>
```

In the relevant portion of the script, I had:

```
var padding = 45,
    h = 500,
    w = 700,
    svg = d3.select("body").select("svg"),
    projection = d3.geo.albersUsa().translate([w/2,h/2]).scale([900]),
    path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
```

The new map, which I've [thrown up onto a block](http://bl.ocks.org/iblind/6c75592f5053a86c5480), remains more or less the same, save a key difference in the way I work with the SVG. First, I only include a div container within the body, rather than an SVG element, like so:

```
  <div id="mapGeo">
  </div>
```

Second, I've changed a few things in the setup of the SVG to account for the container width:

```
    var paddingGeo = {top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10},
        wGeo = parseInt(d3.select('#mapGeo').style('width')),
        wGeo = wGeo - paddingGeo.left - paddingGeo.right,
        mapRatio = .5,
        hGeo = wGeo * mapRatio,
        projection = d3.geo.albersUsa().scale(wGeo).translate([wGeo/2, hGeo/2]);
        path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);
```

After loading my data, I finally append my SVG to the div:

```
        var svgGeo = d3.select('#mapGeo').append('svg')
            .style('height', hGeo+ 'px')
            .style('width', wGeo +'px')
```

Doing this, however, mangles the scatterplot. Is this some sort of ridiculous rookie error I'm coming up across, or is there something more serious happening here?

To sum up: I'd made a slight change to a working map/scatterplot chart which should have allowed me to remain responsive, but ended up throwing a spanner in the works, and now am completely baffled.

Check out the block here: http://bl.ocks.org/iblind/6c75592f5053a86c5480

Comment: In the browser console I can see that all of your position values are NaN. I usually get NaNs if I do arithmetic operation on something that is undefined or null. You mention that position depends on dimensions (width, height). Try going through the code in the debugger in places where you calculating positionings and check if you have some undefined values.

Comment: Also mapGeo div element doesn't have width set. You set it on svg element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's the solution, albeit on that doesn't flatter me much. The issue came where I was setting up the scales:

```
var xScaleGeo = d3.scale
                        .linear()
                        .domain([1, d3.max(data, function(d){ return +d.ratio_rank;})])
                        .rangeRound([0+paddingGeo, wGeo-paddingGeo]);
```

paddingGeo was a variable with the value of 45 in the original, but in the updated code I'd changed it to an object:

```
var paddingGeo = {top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10}
```

Trying to add the object to 0 was the culprit. Sigh.